# What was the cause of the fire on the SpaceX Starship SN15

Tags: spacex, spacex-starship, fire, spacex-starship-sn15

SpaceX Starship SN15 had a successful test flight and touchdown but a few minutes after it landed, a small fire was seen to break out next to the Fins.

- Why did this break out?
- What was the cause of it?

[image]

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/124089/discussion-on-question-by-c0d3x-what-was-the-cause-of-the-fire-on-the-spacex-sta).